# Override minor mode map based on major mode

Tags: key-bindings, prelude

Emacs Prelude binds `C-a` to `crux-move-beginning-of-line` using the following in its `prelude-mode` minor mode map:

```
(define-key map (kbd "C-a") 'crux-move-beginning-of-line)
```

It works good for almost all modes except for `vterm-mode`. In `vterm-mode`, I'd like to overwrite that binding with `vterm-send-C-a`.

I've tried to put the following in a `vterm-mode-hook`:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'vterm-send-C-a)
```

But it just does not work. `C-a` is still bound to `crux-move-beginning-of-line`.

How do I bind `C-a` to `vterm-send-C-a` in `vterm-mode` only?

Answer (score 3):

Well, a pint of complexity comes from the need to override the minor mode mappings based on the major mode. A smarter solution would be to actually unmap the conflicting bindings from the minor mode. It can be done this way:

```
(defun prelude-more-vterm-mode-hook ()
  "Remove prelude-mode keybindings that conflict with vterm-mode."
  (let ((oldmap (cdr (assoc 'prelude-mode minor-mode-map-alist)))
        (newmap (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (set-keymap-parent newmap oldmap)
    (define-key newmap (kbd "C-a") nil)
    (make-local-variable 'minor-mode-overriding-map-alist)
    (push `(prelude-mode . ,newmap) minor-mode-overriding-map-alist)))

(add-hook 'vterm-mode-hook 'prelude-more-vterm-mode-hook)
```

This exact issue is addressed by Bozhidar Batsov [here](https://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/09/25/removing-key-bindings-from-minor-mode-keymaps/).